# Migrating Database in MySql

Tags: sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am migrating database from Microsoft SQL Server to Mysql server
An error occurs when selecting "Microsoft SQL Server" option from Database System

The following is the error:

> connection setup
> an error occured while retrieving values from option dsn from 'mssqlodbcdsn'  error calling python module function dbmssqlire.getdatasource names.

I Have installed ODBC data sources 64 and 32 bit.
reconfigured Mysql.
added System DSN in 64 and 32 bit in 'ODBC data source administrator'.
added a connection in Mysql.
installed mysql connector odbc 8.1.4 win64